# How does this mySQL statement retrieve a single path?

Tags: php, mysql, database, nested-sets

I'm reading this [article](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) and I don't understand how this query works:

```
SELECT parent.name
FROM nested_category AS node,
    nested_category AS parent
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
    AND node.name = 'FLASH'
ORDER BY node.lft;
```

I'm trying to understand how it works because I need to modify it slightly for my program.

I have a data stored in a hierarchical database using the nested set model.

It can be visualized like this:

```
    link
     |
   saria
     |
    roy
     |
   olimar
   /   \
blue    red
 |       |
same    same
```

When given an array like this

> > ['link', 'saria', ,'roy', 'olimar', 'blue', 'same']

I want to return the name/attributes of only the elements along this path.

When I use the above query modified slightly to this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT parent.file_id, parent.owner, parent.name
FROM file_category AS node, file_category AS parent 
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt 
AND node.name = 'same' order by parent.lft
```

I will get a table like this:

```
| file_id | name | owner | 
|    1    | link |  dez  |
|    2    | saria|  madi |
|    3    | roy  |  wrm  |
|    4    | oli  |  mart |
|    5    | blue |  bob  |
|    6    | same |  jim  |
|    7    | red  |  tom  |
|    8    | same |  kim  |
```

but I want a table like this:

```
| file_id | name | owner | 
|    1    | link |  dez  |
|    2    | saria|  madi |
|    3    | roy  |  wrm  |
|    4    | oli  |  mart |
|    5    | blue |  bob  |
|    6    | same |  jim  |
```

I need to a way to go along the path given in the array so I can get to the correct 'same' node.

Comment: how old is that join code

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure. I'm very new to mySQL and php. This is the most helpful article I found related to storing hierarchical data so I've been using it as a reference. Is there a better way to do what I need?

Comment: ah a cross join on self

Comment: how about if you focus on your table schema and your data. publish that. i guess we know what your expected results are

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. You want me to edit my post and add the lft and rgt values into my table? By the way, thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variation does not work because `"same"` is not unique, as assumed by the original query.

Try with

```
WHERE (...) node.id = 6 -- or 8
```

instead of

```
WHERE (...) node.name = 'same'
```

Comment: Yes I was thinking of that as well. I have a search bar where the user will enter a path to a name to look up. They won't know the ID of the last item in the path. Right now i'm trying to figure out how to get the correct ID. Essentially, I need to traverse down the tree along the given path.

Comment: You must be aware that such a tree cannot be represented in a one-dimension line (this is not a path but a graph). In the article you were reading, try the approach described under "Finding the Depth of the Nodes", in particular the second example.

Comment: You're saying some variation of that approach should help me? Hmm, sorry can you give me another clue? I'm not really seeing how that section helps. I was thinking something along the lines of looping through my array in the mySQL statement. Something like child.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt AND child.name = 'next item in array'. but I'm not sure if this is the right approach. Not sure how I would have the mySQL statement know that the next item in the array should be a child of the previous item.